# Specialized C++ template method never called

Tags: c++, template-specialization

And another template specialization problem, which I can't resolve:

terminallog.hh

```
//stripped code

class Terminallog {
public:

    Terminallog();
    Terminallog(int);
    virtual ~Terminallog();

    template <class T>
    Terminallog & operator<<(const T &v);
    template <class T>
    Terminallog & operator<<(const std::vector<T> &v);
    template <class T>
    Terminallog & operator<<(const T v[]);
    Terminallog & operator<<(const char v[]);

    //stripped code 
};
```

terminallog.hh continued (edited thanks to comment)

```
//stripped code 

template <class T>
Terminallog &Terminallog::operator<<(const T &v) {
    std::cout << std::endl;
    this->indent();
    std::cout << v;
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
Terminallog &Terminallog::operator<<(const std::vector<T> &v) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        this->indent();
        std::cout << "Element " << i << ": " << v.at(i);
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
Terminallog &Terminallog::operator<<(const T v[]) {
    unsigned int elements = sizeof (v) / sizeof (v[0]);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        this->indent();
        std::cout << "Element " << i << ": " << v[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

inline
Terminallog &Terminallog::operator<<(const char v[]) {
    std::cout << std::endl;
    this->indent();
    std::cout << v;
    return *this;
}

//stripped code
```

This compiles just fine, no errors. However when I try to do something like:

```
Terminallog clog(3);
int test[] = {5,6,7,8};
clog << test;
```

it always prints me the pointer-address the of the array. In other words the specialized template

```
Terminallog & operator<<(const T v[]);
```

is never called. I also verified this with an additional cout. No matter what I try the program is always calling

```
Terminallog & operator<<(const T &v);
```

and not the specialization. Obviously there has to be an error in my code, however I can't find it.

Comment: Don't put templates in `.cpp` (or `.cc` in your case) files. Template classes are most of the time "header-only" classes, because the compiler need to know the exact code of each templated function to generate it for each used type.

Comment: Hrm, which compiler?  Visual studio 2010 gives me "Element 0: 5"

Comment: Ohh, uups, you are absolutly correct. This was a typo. Sorry. They are in the header.

Comment: uhh? My compiler is g++ 4.4.5. This is strange ...

Comment: Keep calm and clog on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bet is that conversion rules are applied here. Since there is no exact match for `int [5]` (which is the actual type of your array), your array will decay to `int*` and the overload with `const T&` will be chosen, since it will be a better match than `const T v[]` (which is treated as `const T* v`).

See @sth 's answer for a detailed explanation on the overload resolution mechanism in this case.

What if you try:

```
template <class T, size_t n>
Terminallog & operator<<(const T (&v)[n]);
```

instead ?

By the way the `sizeof` stuff in the definition of the overload with `T[]` is plain wrong. You cannot get the size this way. Again the array will decay to a pointer and `elements` will always be `sizeof(T*) / sizeof(T)`.

Comment: Wow, thanks man, absolutly correct. Code runs perfectly smooth now. Very cool. I am deeply impressed. Reading foreign code, spotting mistakes and giving a perfect explanation. Thank you so much... P.S.: surprisingly the code getting all elements of the array works that way. The compiler is probably doing something automatically. However thank you neverhteless

Comment: @ftiaronsem: indeed, `sizeof(T(&)[n]) = n * sizeof(T)`. Note that you can set `elements = n` here.

Comment: You may omit reference sign: `template<class T,size_t n> Terminallog& operator<<(const T v[n]);` IMHO it looks more natural.

Comment: @Serge: This does not work. `T v[n]` is exactly the same as `T*`, whereas a reference to an array has a size associated with it.

Comment: Even if I specify the size explicitly? Hmm... May be you're right. Seems strange.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, you define several overloaded function templates (They are not specializations of some generic template, they are separate overloads. But there is nothing wrong with that, there is no reason they would have to be specializations.)

One of these templates has a parameter declaration of `const T v[]`. Since arrays cannot be passed by value, this is interpreted by the compiler just the same as if the parameter was declared `const T *v`.

For the array in questions, which ends up to be of type `int[5]`, the compiler has to chose between two matching templates. The best match is determined by the number and type of conversions needed, according to §13.3.3.1.1 (Table 10) in the standard.

- The `const T&` template matches for `T = int[5]`. According to §13.3.3.1.4/2 converting the `int[5]` to a const `int(&)[5]` parameter requires the same conversions as converting an `int[5]` to a const `int[5]`. This is one qualification conversion (adding a `const`).
- The `const T*` template matches for `T = int`. Converting a `int[5]` to a `const int*` requires two conversions. First and array-to-pointer conversion (`int[5]` to `int*`), then a qualification conversion (`int*` to `const int*`).

All these conversions qualify as "exact matches", but since the second template would require two such conversions while the first template requires only one, the first template is a better match.

To get the "correct" match, you could remove the `const` from the parameter of the second template, or add an additional template for non-const pointers that just calls the const version:

```
template <class T>
Terminallog& Terminallog::operator<<(T *v) {
   *this << static_cast<const T*>(v);
}
```

All that being said, note that you cannot get the array length with `sizeof` in a function like this. A template with an additional size parameter like suggested by Alexandre C. in his answer might be a better choice for that.

Comment: Well explained. Indeed, for overload resolution, array arguments (and function arguments) are treated like pointers before everything. Then, conversion rules apply.

Comment: Casting `T*` to `const T*` doesn't require `const_cast`. It is perfectly OK to use the safest `static_cast<const T*>(v)`. const_cast is used to cast away `const` (like this `const T* p = &something; const_cast<T*>(p)->some_non_const_member = 0;`) that is a very bad taste (and sometimes may be unsafe - e.g. if memory is write protected or something).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you don't have specializations here, but overloaded functions.

Then, I assume the problem is as follows:

```
int test[] = {5,6,7,8}; // <-- this guy is "decayed" to int* in next call
clog << test;
```

So now during overloading resolution compiler chooses between

```
template <class T>
Terminallog & operator<<(const T &v);

template <class T>
Terminallog & operator<<(const T v[]);
```

First one is exact match, so it "wins".

Comment: thanks for this answer. This seems to be the right explanation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are not doing template specialization:

```
template <class T>
Terminallog & operator<<(const T v[]);
Terminallog & operator<<(const char v[]);
```

are two different functions.  <del>If you tried to define an output where `T` is of type `char` then your compiler should complain of an ambiguity</del>.  To indicate that you are specializing a template, as ssteinberg notes, you need to use the `template<>` notation.

In this case, however, this probably won't help you as I don't believe you can specialize member functions (maybe you can if they are static?).  So your compiler will complain if you try to follow ssteinberg's advice.    You need to template the whole class, and then specialize individual functions.

The following link might provide some help, http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#mem-fun-specialisation

**EDIT:**

The following might be illustrative:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Terminallog { 
public:

  Terminallog(){};
  Terminallog(int){};
  virtual ~Terminallog(){};

  //general vector output: will be specialized for vectors of chars
  Terminallog & 
  operator<<(const std::vector<T> &v);

  //general reference output: will be specialized for chars
  Terminallog & operator<<(const T &v);

  //general pointer output: will be specialised for char pointers
  Terminallog & operator<<(const T* v);

  //stripped code 
};

//general code for reference type
 template <class T>
 Terminallog<T>&
 Terminallog<T>::operator<<(const T &v) {
   std::cout<<"This general reference"<<std::endl;
     return *this;
 }

//specialisation for chars reference
template <>  //as noted by ssteinberg
Terminallog<char>&
Terminallog<char>::operator<<(const char &v) {
  std::cout<<"This is for chars"<<std::endl;
  return *this;
}

//general code for pointer type
 template <class T>
 Terminallog<T>&
 Terminallog<T>::operator<<(const T* v) {
   std::cout<<"This general pointers"<<std::endl;
     return *this;
 }

//specialisation for chars pointer
//as noted by alexandre your array will decay to this....
template <>  
Terminallog<char>&
Terminallog<char>::operator<<(const char* v) {
  std::cout<<"This is for chars pointers"<<std::endl;
  return *this;
}


//Non specialised vector
template <class T>
Terminallog<T>&
Terminallog<T>::operator<<(const std::vector<T> &v) {
  std::cout<<"This general vector"<<std::endl;
  return *this;
}

//specialisation for  vector of chars
template <>
Terminallog<char>&
Terminallog<char>::operator<<(const std::vector<char> &v) {
  std::cout<<"This is a vector of chars"<<std::endl;
  return *this;
}

int
main  (int ac, char **av)
{
  Terminallog<int> ilog(3);
  int testint[] = {5,6,7,8};
  std::vector<int> testvi;
  testvi.push_back(1);
  testvi.push_back(3);
  testvi.push_back(5);

  Terminallog<char> clog(3);
  char testchar[] = {5,6,7,8};
  std::vector<char> testvc;
  testvc.push_back(1);
  testvc.push_back(3);
  testvc.push_back(5);

  ilog << testint;
  ilog << testvi;
  clog << testchar;
  clog << testvc;


}
```

Output is

```
This general pointers
This general vector
This is for chars pointers
This is a vector of chars
```

Comment: It's ok to have several overloaded functions of the same name, if they take different parameters. There is no need to make them specializations, overloads should just be fine.

Comment: "then your compiler should complain of an ambiguity": nope, it will always prefer the non template overload to the template one.

Comment: @Alexandre Thanks, just tried it out and was surprised that the compiler didn't complain.  Now I know why

Comment: overload resolution rules are damn complex indeed.

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. I indeed learned a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First: there is no such thing as extern templates (there was export keyword in C++ standard but it was ignored by major compiler producers like MS and GNU and now seems abandoned). So you have to put template function bodies in header file.

Second: better forget partial template specialization. It is not supported well enough, e.g. MS provides only very limited support for partial class template specialization (for pointers, references, pointer to member and function pointers [(Look here)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3967w96f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)). So better just don't use it. But you can use fully explicit template specialization.

Third: you don't really have any template specializations in your code

```
template <class T>
Terminallog & operator<<(const T &v);
template <class T>
Terminallog & operator<<(const std::vector<T> &v);
template <class T>
Terminallog & operator<<(const T v[]);
```

are three distinct function templates and

```
Terminallog & operator<<(const char v[]);
```

is just function.

The right syntax for function template specializations is this

```
template <class T>
Terminallog& out(const T& v)
{
// default implementation
}

template <class T>
Terminallog& out< std::vector<T> >(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
// partially specialized implementation
}

template <>
Terminallog& out<double>(const double& v)
{
// fully specialized implementation
}
```

But it is not really the point. The overloading resolution must still lead to the most specialized function or function template (if no such function exist) according to the rules defined in the standard. But I'm not sure that fully compliant C++ implementation exist (except Comeau C++ developed by standard authors used by nobody). I think that if you have two overloads that match exactly or none of them (and implicit conversion is required) you may have problems with non-compliance.

**ALSO NOTE:**

Function template specializations are allowed in namespace scope only. It means that you may not declare member function template specializations. But of course you may define overloads like you did.

Comment: Ahh,thank you very much. I am new to template programming, so this definitly furthered my understandig. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to put `template<>` in front of `Terminallog & operator<<(const char v[]);` to tell the compiler that you're specializing a template.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit specialized template instantiation:

```
inline template<>
Terminallog & operator<<(const char v[]);
```

Something like this. My C++ is rusty.

Comment: `Terminallog` isn't templated, so no need for `Terminallog<char>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly it isn't solving the problem. The compiler gives me: src/../inc/terminallog.hh:30:14: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class Terminallog’
src/../inc/terminallog.hh:30:16: error: ‘Terminallog’ is not a template
src/../inc/terminallog.hh:31:5: error: field ‘Terminallog’ has incomplete type
src/../inc/terminallog.hh:31:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘&’ token
src/../inc/terminallog.hh:162:16: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
src/../inc/terminallog.hh:170:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘template

Comment: Thanks to xeos comment it now gives me a little bit less errors: src/../inc/terminallog.hh:30:14: error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope ‘class Terminallog’
src/../inc/terminallog.hh:162:16: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
src/../inc/terminallog.hh:170:1: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘template’
In file included from src/terminallog.cc:8:0:

Comment: `inline` should be after `template<>` and there should be `Terminallog::` before `operator<<`.